# cheat sheet for Xtend?

Tags: xtend

I am learning [Xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/). Does anyone has a cheat sheet of Xtend 2.3 M7 to share? I did a quick search on Google but could not find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a cheat sheet available. The [reference documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation.html) and the [website](http://xtend-lang.org) are the best official available resources. Do you have something concrete in mind that you'd expect to find on such a cheat sheet?

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. I was just looking for an overview of the Xtend features that would nicely fit on 1 page. The reference documentation is excellent, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

see here http://jadogg.phatcode.net/wp/?p=49
I just made one,follow the link to get the pdf

Comment: note:this is based on the latest docs,i'll give you the word file if anyone wants to modify it